# Button component wont show linktext inside <Link>

Tags: html, reactjs

I expect that the text of the p tag inside the Link to be white, but for some reason the link text won't display. It appears to be hidden and only displays once I hover over the button. When I hover it is only barely visible. Can it be due to the `<Link>`?

I have appended the code and a picture that shows my button below.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated :)

Index.js file

```
<div class="py-4">
  <Button>
    <div className="p-1">
      <Link to="/contact">
        <p>Get in contact</p>
      </Link>
    </div> 
  </Button>
</div>
```

Button component:

```
import React from 'react';

const sizes = {
  default: `py-3 px-8`,
  lg: `py-4 px-12`,
  xl: `py-5 px-16 text-lg`
};

const Button = ({ children, className = '', size }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={`
        ${sizes[size] || sizes.default}
        ${className}
        bg-primary
        hover:bg-primary-darker
        rounded
        text-white
      `}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

picture of button, which should show get in contact
[image]

Comment: It's impossible for us to tell with what you've provided. Presumably you're using Tailwind, but you've not mentioned it. If I had to speculate, I'd agree that yes, your `<Link />` (`<a />`) uses a colour that matches `bg-primary`. Also note that the HTML that this will render (`button > div > a > p`) is invalid according to to HTML5 spec.

Comment: Hi George. 
Thx for commenting. I am using Tailwind. I now know for sure that the <Link> uses a similar color to bg-primary. Is there a way to change the color of the <Link>? I have tried with p-style, but that does not work.

Comment: I have removed the <p> and added class="text-white" to the <Link> and this has solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :
 `<Link to="/contact" style={{color:'#fff'}}>Get in contact </Link>`
or add your own className with the color u wanna use